# Why this SQL code showing error of "missing right parenthesis"?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE PoolActivity_T 
(PoolID          NUMBER(11,0)       NOT NULL,
ServiceDate      DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE   NOT NULL,
ActivityID       NUMBER(11,0)   NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PoolActivity_PK PRIMARY KEY (PoolID,ServiceDate,ActivityID)
CONSTRAINT PoolActivity_FK FOREIGN KEY (PoolID) 
REFERENCES PoolVisit_T(PoolID),
CONSTRAINT PoolActivity_FK FOREIGN KEY (ActivityID) 
REFERENCES Activity_T (ActivityID)
);
```

Here is my code and I can not figure out why comes the error.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_T 
(CustomerID          NUMBER(11,0)       NOT NULL,
CustomerFname          VARCHAR2(25),
CustomerMname          VARCHAR2(25),
CustomerLname          VARCHAR2(25),
CustomerAddress1          VARCHAR2(50),
CustomerAddress2          VARCHAR2(50),
CustomerCity          VARCHAR2(25), 
CustomerState          CHAR(2), 
CustomerZipCode         NUMBER(5,0),
CustomerPhoneNumber     NUMBER(11,0),
CONSTRAINT Customer_PK PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);

CREATE TABLE Pool_T     
(PoolID          NUMBER(11,0)       NOT NULL,
PoolAddress1    VARCHAR2(25),
PoolAddress2        VARCHAR2(25),
PoolCity        VARCHAR2(25),
PoolState       VARCHAR2(25),
PoolZipCode     NUMBER(5,0),
TypeSurface     VARCHAR2(9),
Gallon      INTEGER,
Filters     VARCHAR2(25),
VisitPerMonth   INTEGER,    
Dates           DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
Fee         NUMBER(11,0),
CONSTRAINT Pool_PK PRIMARY KEY (PoolID)
);

CREATE TABLE PoolVisit_T 
(PoolID          NUMBER(11,0)       NOT NULL,
ServiceDate      DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE   NOT NULL,
LengthStay       INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT Poolvisit_PK PRIMARY KEY (PoolID,ServiceDate)
CONSTRAINT PoolVisit_FK FOREIGN KEY (PoolID) 
REFERENCES Pool_T (PoolID)
);

CREATE TABLE PoolActivity_T 
(PoolID          NUMBER(11,0)       NOT NULL,
ServiceDate      DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE   NOT NULL,
ActivityID       NUMBER(11,0)   NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PoolActivity_PK PRIMARY KEY (PoolID,ServiceDate,ActivityID)
CONSTRAINT PoolActivity_FK FOREIGN KEY (PoolID) 
REFERENCES PoolVisit_T(PoolID),
CONSTRAINT PoolActivity_FK FOREIGN KEY (ActivityID) 
REFERENCES Activity_T (ActivityID)
);

CREATE TABLE PoolChemical_T 
(PoolID          NUMBER(11,0)       NOT NULL, 
ServiceDate     DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE    NOT NULL,
ChemicalName    VARCHAR2(25)        NOT NULL,
Quantity        INTEGER,
Cost            NUMBER(11,2),
CONSTRAINT PoolChemical_PK PRIMARY KEY (PoolID,ServiceDate,ChemicalName)
CONSTRAINT PoolChemical_FK FOREIGN KEY (PoolID) 
REFERENCES PoolVisit_T(PoolID)
CONSTRAINT PoolChemical_FK FOREIGN KEY (ChemicalName) 
REFERENCES Chemical_T(ChemicalName)
);

CREATE TABLE Activity_T 
(ActivityID          NUMBER(11,0)       NOT NULL,
ActivityDesc         VARCHAR2(500), 
CONSTRAINT Activity_PK PRIMARY KEY (ActivityID));

CREATE TABLE Chemical_T 
(ChemicalName        VARCHAR2(25)       NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Chemical_PK PRIMARY KEY (ChemicalName));
```

Comment: not uml related, probably oracle ( not mysql )

Comment: how can I indent so many codes at one time?

Comment: @MarioHo - [see the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't just in the table you highlighted, it's also in the one before, `PoolVisit_T`. In both, you're just missing a comma after the primary key constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE PoolVisit_T 
(PoolID          NUMBER(11,0)       NOT NULL,
ServiceDate      DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE   NOT NULL,
LengthStay       INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT Poolvisit_PK PRIMARY KEY (PoolID,ServiceDate), -- was missing comma
CONSTRAINT PoolVisit_FK FOREIGN KEY (PoolID) 
REFERENCES Pool_T (PoolID)
);

CREATE TABLE PoolActivity_T 
(PoolID          NUMBER(11,0)       NOT NULL,
ServiceDate      DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE   NOT NULL,
ActivityID       NUMBER(11,0)   NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PoolActivity_PK PRIMARY KEY (PoolID,ServiceDate,ActivityID), -- was missing
CONSTRAINT PoolActivity_FK FOREIGN KEY (PoolID) 
REFERENCES PoolVisit_T(PoolID),
CONSTRAINT PoolActivity_FK FOREIGN KEY (ActivityID) 
REFERENCES Activity_T (ActivityID)
);
```

And you're missing two in the one after that:

```
CREATE TABLE PoolChemical_T 
(PoolID          NUMBER(11,0)       NOT NULL, 
ServiceDate     DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE    NOT NULL,
ChemicalName    VARCHAR2(25)        NOT NULL,
Quantity        INTEGER,
Cost            NUMBER(11,2),
CONSTRAINT PoolChemical_PK PRIMARY KEY (PoolID,ServiceDate,ChemicalName), -- was missing
CONSTRAINT PoolChemical_FK FOREIGN KEY (PoolID) 
REFERENCES PoolVisit_T(PoolID), -- was missing
CONSTRAINT PoolChemical_FK FOREIGN KEY (ChemicalName) 
REFERENCES Chemical_T(ChemicalName)
);
```

If you use an IDE like SQL Developer it will highlight syntax problems like this as you go.

But you still have issues; your `PoolActivity_T` foreign key:

```
CONSTRAINT PoolActivity_FK FOREIGN KEY (PoolID) 
REFERENCES PoolVisit_T(PoolID),
```

is referring only to the `PoolID`, but the primary key on `PoolVisit_T` and the primary key has two columns, so that needs to be:

```
CONSTRAINT PoolActivity_FK FOREIGN KEY (PoolID,ServiceDate) 
REFERENCES PoolVisit_T(PoolID,ServiceDate),
```

And you've used the same FK name for two constraints, so the next bit is:

```
CONSTRAINT PoolActivity_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (ActivityID) 
REFERENCES Activity_T (ActivityID)
```

(but pick more descriptive FK names, perhaps), *and* you have to create the `Activity_T` table before this one.

And similar issues with `PoolChemical_T`:

```
CONSTRAINT PoolChemical_PK PRIMARY KEY (PoolID,ServiceDate,ChemicalName),
CONSTRAINT PoolChemical_FK FOREIGN KEY (PoolID,ServiceDate) 
REFERENCES PoolVisit_T(PoolID,ServiceDate),
CONSTRAINT PoolChemical_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (ChemicalName)
REFERENCES Chemical_T(ChemicalName)
```

and create `Chemical_T` first.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4140d/1) with all tables created.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Would you like to tell me how to indent all my code?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really a depressed night doing my uml homework. It seems easy. But once I ran it, lots of errors came out.

Comment: Oh! I mixed those things up. It should be SQL actually. I think I need to have a rest. Thank you again!